# How to remove Touchbar animations?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, keyboard, touch-bar, animation

On the 2016/2017 MacBook Pro's the Touchbar animations are slow. After a little while I've become used to the keyboard and Touchbar. But the one thing I would like to speed up is the transitions.

Say for instance you are playing music on Spotify while working. They you hit the media button to expand the view for full controls. It only takes a second... but it still takes a whole second. When you know what you want and you can navigate quickly the animation is agonising.

Is there a terminal command to remove Touchbar animations, forcing the new buttons to appear immediately?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution in the last year? The touch by animations are very annoying for me especially when changing brightness and volume (tapping buttons were so much faster!)

Comment: I've got to wait for the volume switch to animate and fully expand. If I swipe too soon, I hit the right edge, and then I've gotta lift and swipe again

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy Not yet, I was hoping it would be similar to removing the [dock animations](https://9to5mac.com/2017/05/09/macos-dock-autohide-animation-video) but haven't found anything.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy What I did find was [better touch tool](https://folivora.ai) which allows you to customise the touch bar and add your own buttons, its not explicitly stated anywhere but using it you can swap between your own setup and the default apple setup using **fn**.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to the problem, but small tip to quickly change *brightness* and *volume* without waiting for full animation to expand or holding fn key to switch to the buttons.

Just quickly swipe across the icon in the direction you wan't to change (to the left - decrease value / to the right - increase)

or

You can tap&**hold**, and then swipe where you wanted (your finger should ended up being offset from where the knob is). In this case expanding animation will be played, but you save some time not needing to navigate to the knob or buttons